# R : Merge several dataframes from a list into a single dataframe with differentiation between dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I need to join the dataframes of a list into a single dataframe, in which there is some kind of separation or differentiation between each of the dataframes.

my list :

```
print(list1)

[[1]]
         DATE HHr     Tavg    RAIN BU FU BUA FUA ABU AFU APP
2  2019-11-19   0 8.655000 10.9935  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
3  2019-11-20   0 9.500000  1.8565  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
4  2019-11-21   0 9.120000  9.3120  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
5  2019-11-22   0 8.150000  9.9430  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
6  2019-11-23   0 8.825000  9.0780  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
7  2019-11-25   4 7.284648 12.7500  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
8  2019-11-26   1 7.284648 12.7500  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
9  2019-11-27   0 7.284648 12.7500  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
10 2019-11-28   0 7.284648 12.7500  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
11 2019-11-29   0 7.284648 12.7500  0  0   0   0   0   0   0

[[2]]
         DATE HHr     Tavg      RAIN BU FU BUA FUA ABU AFU APP
2  2019-11-19   6 24.80000  6.103500  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
3  2019-11-20   8 25.44500 10.302000  1  0   1   0   0   0   0
4  2019-11-21   5 25.57000  0.000000  0  0   1   0   0   0   0
5  2019-11-22   8 26.24000  9.478000  1  0   2   0   0   0   0
6  2019-11-23  11 24.28500 29.974001  2  0   4   0   0   0   0
7  2019-11-25  10 23.48423  2.416667  2  0   6   0   0   0   0
8  2019-11-26   9 23.48423  2.416667  1  0   7   0   0   0   0
9  2019-11-27  16 23.48423  2.416667  4  0  11   0   0   0   0
10 2019-11-28   9 23.48423  2.416667  1  0  12   0   0   0   0
11 2019-11-29   0 23.48423  2.416667  0  0  12   0   0   0   0
```

I tried the following code but it returns an entire run dataframe, without deference between dataframes in the original list.

```
  data <- ldply(list1)
  print(data)

     DATE HHr      Tavg      RAIN BU FU BUA FUA ABU AFU APP
1  2019-11-19   0  8.655000 10.993500  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
2  2019-11-20   0  9.500000  1.856500  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
3  2019-11-21   0  9.120000  9.312000  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
4  2019-11-22   0  8.150000  9.943000  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
5  2019-11-23   0  8.825000  9.078000  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
6  2019-11-25   4  7.284648 12.750000  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
7  2019-11-26   1  7.284648 12.750000  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
8  2019-11-27   0  7.284648 12.750000  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
9  2019-11-28   0  7.284648 12.750000  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
10 2019-11-29   0  7.284648 12.750000  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
11 2019-11-19   6 24.800000  6.103500  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
12 2019-11-20   8 25.445000 10.302000  1  0   1   0   0   0   0
13 2019-11-21   5 25.570000  0.000000  0  0   1   0   0   0   0
14 2019-11-22   8 26.240000  9.478000  1  0   2   0   0   0   0
15 2019-11-23  11 24.285000 29.974001  2  0   4   0   0   0   0
16 2019-11-25  10 23.484231  2.416667  2  0   6   0   0   0   0
17 2019-11-26   9 23.484231  2.416667  1  0   7   0   0   0   0
18 2019-11-27  16 23.484231  2.416667  4  0  11   0   0   0   0
19 2019-11-28   9 23.484231  2.416667  1  0  12   0   0   0   0
20 2019-11-29   0 23.484231  2.416667  0  0  12   0   0   0   0
```

Expected result :

```
     DATE HHr      Tavg      RAIN BU FU BUA FUA ABU AFU APP

DATA 1
1  2019-11-19   0  8.655000 10.993500  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
2  2019-11-20   0  9.500000  1.856500  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
3  2019-11-21   0  9.120000  9.312000  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
4  2019-11-22   0  8.150000  9.943000  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
5  2019-11-23   0  8.825000  9.078000  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
6  2019-11-25   4  7.284648 12.750000  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
7  2019-11-26   1  7.284648 12.750000  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
8  2019-11-27   0  7.284648 12.750000  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
9  2019-11-28   0  7.284648 12.750000  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
10 2019-11-29   0  7.284648 12.750000  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
DATA 2
11 2019-11-19   6 24.800000  6.103500  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
12 2019-11-20   8 25.445000 10.302000  1  0   1   0   0   0   0
13 2019-11-21   5 25.570000  0.000000  0  0   1   0   0   0   0
14 2019-11-22   8 26.240000  9.478000  1  0   2   0   0   0   0
15 2019-11-23  11 24.285000 29.974001  2  0   4   0   0   0   0
16 2019-11-25  10 23.484231  2.416667  2  0   6   0   0   0   0
17 2019-11-26   9 23.484231  2.416667  1  0   7   0   0   0   0
18 2019-11-27  16 23.484231  2.416667  4  0  11   0   0   0   0
19 2019-11-28   9 23.484231  2.416667  1  0  12   0   0   0   0
20 2019-11-29   0 23.484231  2.416667  0  0  12   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Is this for printing? or do you just need an identifier column?

Comment: The final dataframe is saved as a .csv

Answer (score 3):

We can use `rbind_list` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list1, idcol = "id")
```

---

Or using `base R` with `Map`

```
do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, list1, id= seq_along(list1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you could create an `id` column which would add a unique number to each dataframe in the list.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(list1),function(x) transform(list1[[x]], id =  x)))

#          DATE HHr      Tavg      RAIN BU FU BUA FUA ABU AFU APP id
#2   2019-11-19   0  8.655000 10.993500  0  0   0   0   0   0   0  1
#3   2019-11-20   0  9.500000  1.856500  0  0   0   0   0   0   0  1
#4   2019-11-21   0  9.120000  9.312000  0  0   0   0   0   0   0  1
#5   2019-11-22   0  8.150000  9.943000  0  0   0   0   0   0   0  1
#6   2019-11-23   0  8.825000  9.078000  0  0   0   0   0   0   0  1
#7   2019-11-25   4  7.284648 12.750000  0  0   0   0   0   0   0  1
#8   2019-11-26   1  7.284648 12.750000  0  0   0   0   0   0   0  1
#9   2019-11-27   0  7.284648 12.750000  0  0   0   0   0   0   0  1
#10  2019-11-28   0  7.284648 12.750000  0  0   0   0   0   0   0  1
#11  2019-11-29   0  7.284648 12.750000  0  0   0   0   0   0   0  1
#21  2019-11-19   6 24.800000  6.103500  0  0   0   0   0   0   0  2
#31  2019-11-20   8 25.445000 10.302000  1  0   1   0   0   0   0  2
#41  2019-11-21   5 25.570000  0.000000  0  0   1   0   0   0   0  2
#51  2019-11-22   8 26.240000  9.478000  1  0   2   0   0   0   0  2
#61  2019-11-23  11 24.285000 29.974001  2  0   4   0   0   0   0  2
#71  2019-11-25  10 23.484230  2.416667  2  0   6   0   0   0   0  2
#81  2019-11-26   9 23.484230  2.416667  1  0   7   0   0   0   0  2
#91  2019-11-27  16 23.484230  2.416667  4  0  11   0   0   0   0  2
#101 2019-11-28   9 23.484230  2.416667  1  0  12   0   0   0   0  2
#111 2019-11-29   0 23.484230  2.416667  0  0  12   0   0   0   0  2
```

---

Or similar to suggestion from @IceCreamTouCan, you can use `dplyr::bind_rows` with a `.id` argument

```
dplyr::bind_rows(list1, .id = "id")
```

Note that in case of named list this would assign name as `id` column.

**data**

```
list1 <- list(structure(list(DATE = structure(1:10, .Label = c("2019-11-19", 
"2019-11-20", "2019-11-21", "2019-11-22", "2019-11-23", "2019-11-25", 
"2019-11-26", "2019-11-27", "2019-11-28", "2019-11-29"), class = "factor"), 
HHr = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Tavg = c(8.655, 
9.5, 9.12, 8.15, 8.825, 7.284648, 7.284648, 7.284648, 7.284648, 
7.284648), RAIN = c(10.9935, 1.8565, 9.312, 9.943, 9.078, 
12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 12.75), BU = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), FU = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), BUA = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), FUA = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ABU = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AFU = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), APP = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11")), structure(list(
DATE = structure(1:10, .Label = c("2019-11-19", "2019-11-20", 
"2019-11-21", "2019-11-22", "2019-11-23", "2019-11-25", "2019-11-26", 
"2019-11-27", "2019-11-28", "2019-11-29"), class = "factor"), 
HHr = c(6L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 16L, 9L, 0L), Tavg = c(24.8, 
25.445, 25.57, 26.24, 24.285, 23.48423, 23.48423, 23.48423, 
23.48423, 23.48423), RAIN = c(6.1035, 10.302, 0, 9.478, 29.974001, 
2.416667, 2.416667, 2.416667, 2.416667, 2.416667), BU = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 0L), FU = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), BUA = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 
7L, 11L, 12L, 12L), FUA = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), ABU = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
AFU = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), APP = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11")))
```